# How to handle encodings in knitr spin_child

Tags: r, knitr, knitr-spin

Following recommendations on https://yihui.name/en/2018/11/biggest-regret-knitr, I started saving my .R files with UTF-8 encoding (using RStudios "Save with encoding"). Seems to work well, until it comes to using spin_child.

Under Windows, for example I have a file *mainfile.R* with this code:

```
print("Bär 1"); spin_child("subfile.R")
```

*subfile.R* has this code:

```
print("Bär 2")
```

In RStudio under Windows, I run

```
rmarkdown::render("mainfile.R", encoding = "UTF-8")
```

If both files are saved with encoding UTF-8, Bär 1 comes out fine, but Bär 2 comes out as "BÃ¤r 2" (which seems like an encoding problem to me).
Interestingly, if I change encoding of subfile.R to ISO-8859-1 (System default), both Bär come out correctly.
It seems strange to me that I should have to use different encodings for different files, so I'm wonderning what I have to do if the input file for spin_child ist UTF-8 as well?

Comment: That is a bug. I'll fix it soon.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in **knitr**, and I just [fixed it on Github](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/commit/7e43c65939245ec3dd6cddc8f1644cbcd9536216). Please try the development version and continue using UTF-8:

```r
remotes::install_github('yihui/knitr')
```

Comment: Thanks, yes this seems to fix the problem.